# How to assign unique id for bootstrap checkbox badges?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, badge

I am working on a admin page where you can list all the users. In a table you can see each user permissions.

I want to use a checkbox that automatically updates the database column value either to `true` or `false` by using ajax (according to a given permission represented by a badge checkbox).

I have found this [badge checkbox](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/badgebox-css-checkbox-badge). And the [jsfiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/latlov/ho1uocq4/2/).

However, there is a problem. When there is more than one row, the checkbox functionality does not work anymore. Moreover, if you change the default id of any badge, this does not work any longer as shown [now in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/latlov/ho1uocq4/4/).

How can I make these badges work for several rows and with their own IDs?

For example, I want to assign id="user-{{id}}-permissionName" instead of id="success" for all the rows.

Comment: `id` attribute is meant to be unique. Use something like `data-id` attribute

Comment: Of course. That is what I mean ;)

Comment: Oops :) I've misunderstood the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could actually change the default `id` of any `badge` and It actually works if you change `id` but you need to change it's parent `label` element's `for` property too and it is used to target particular `checkbox`

For ex:

```
<label for="danger1" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs">Query 
     <input type="checkbox" id="danger1" class="badgebox"/>
     <span class="badge">&check;</span>
</label>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ho1uocq4/5/)**

Comment: Glad it did.. Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 2):

When you have rows of repeating elements that may have multiple actions contained within it is generally simplest to store the data needed on the row itself. Then use classes or data attributes to define the types of controls.

```
<div class="row" data-id="{{id}}" data-permission="user-{{id}}-permissionName">
   <input type="checkbox" data-action="delete" class="btn btn-delete">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var $row = $(this).closest('.row'),
        rowData = $row.data();
    var action = $(this).data('action');
    var id = rowData.id;
    var permission = rowData.permission;        
});
```